# Vectorize code in big pandas Dataframe, where each row should be treated as a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a big pandas Dataframe, which essentially has a structure like the following one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 20)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'))
```

Each of the 'rows' is an array of numbers. e.g.:

```
row_one = df.iloc[0, :].values
row_two = df.iloc[1, :].values
....
```

I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient (np.corrcoef) between all combination of rows, e. g.:

```
np.corrcoef(row_one, row_one)[0][1]
np.corrcoef(row_one, row_two)[0][1]
np.corrcoef(row_one, row_three)[0][1]
....
np.corrcoef(row_two, row_one)[0][1]
np.corrcoef(row_one, row_two)[0][1]
np.corrcoef(row_one, row_three)[0][1]
...
```

I want to obtain a DataFrame in the end that will hold all the correlation coefficients (CC) for all combinations. I can't figure out how to vectorize the code. My original dataframe is pretty huge, wherefore I would be grateful for any advice how to speed up the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do so is to use panda's built-in method [`.corr()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html). Note however that it computes it over columns by default:

> Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values

So you could do:

```
df.T.corr()
```

You can check any pair correlation doing:

```
row_one = df.iloc[0, :].values
row_two = df.iloc[1, :].values
np.corrcoef(row_one,row_two)
```

---

As a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

  0         1         2
0  1.000000 -0.479317 -0.921551
1 -0.479317  1.000000  0.782467
2 -0.921551  0.782467  1.000000
```

Checking on rows `0` and `1` for instance you can see that the result is the same:

```
row_one = df.iloc[0, :].values
row_two = df.iloc[1, :].values
np.corrcoef(row_one,row_two)

array([[ 1.        , -0.47931716],
       [-0.47931716,  1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a method for that already: `corr`. It works on the columns so you just need to transpose your dataframe.

```
corr_matrix = df.T.corr()
```

It'll generate a correlation matrix where you can find the correlation coefficient between datasets. So coefficient for the 4th and 7th dataset is `corr_matrix.iloc[3, 6]` (or `corr_matrix.iloc[6, 3]` since it's symmetric).